# Algebra problem involving Q functions

Tags: calculus, analysis, statistics

I have the following algebra problem, which is actually the end-part of my bigger research problem.

Let $a$, $b$ and $m$ be reals with $a<b$.

Also, let $Q(\cdot)$ denote the Gaussian Q-function, i.e., $Q(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{x}^{\infty} e^{-t^2/2} dt$.

I have the quantities

$b_{\infty} = e^{-\frac{m^2}{2}} \left[ Q(a) - Q(b) \right]$

$b_0 = \sqrt{[Q(a+m) - Q(b+m)][Q(a-m) - Q(b-m)]}$

$b_1 = \sqrt{[Q(a+m) - Q(t+m)][Q(a-m) - Q(t-m)]} + \sqrt{[Q(t+m) - Q(b+m)][Q(t-m) - Q(b-m)]}$

and I am trying to prove that, for any $a<b$, and for any $m$, there is a $a<t<b$ such that $b_1^2 \leq b_0 b_{\infty}$.

I am certain that such $t$ exists, having done thourough simulations on the matter, but I cant show it anallytically. If you have a good eye in algebra, I would appreciate your input.

Comment: Any inputs? I still cant solve it

Comment: Has anybody tried it?

Comment: Its not a shame to admit it. I am desperate